# Male cat attacking female cat

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, multi-pet-families

We have 2 cats - one male and one female, which are 8 months old now. Both are siblings and they were very attached to each other as we separated them from mom when they were only 2 months old.

I recently neutered my female cat around 15 days ago. In the whole process of neutering, we kept both cats in separate rooms. Now my male cat is attacking female cat. What would be the reason?

We are still using medicine on female cats stitches, could that smell be what's provoking male cat's attacks?

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to [Cat behaving badly](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21073/cat-behaving-badly) and especially [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21052/why-one-of-my-tomcat-is-being-mean-to-his-brothers)

Answer (score -1):

It may be that that its scent smells different and that the male cat does not recognise his sister. Scent is very important to cats. Hope your cats’ fighting stops soon!

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, this answer is a bit short, please add some more information if you could.